# How do I use Flask to show a generated matplotlib image on the same screen as the form?

Tags: python, matplotlib, web, flask

Basically I am using matplotlib to generate charts that I want to then display directly to the user. The user fills out a form and the variables are passed to a few methods that create the chart. The code I currently have will show only the image and get rid of the form. Is it possible to display the image on the page so that the user can modify the queries/connections and see the results with each subsequent form submission?

Here is my code:

```
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_file, redirect, url_for
import flask
import MultipleDatabasesLib as mdl
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

app = Flask(__name__)

xlabel = ""
ylabel = ""
graph_title = ""

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('my-form.html')


@app.route('/get_form_vals', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def form_vals():

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df_group = pd.DataFrame()
    fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
    fig_size[0] = 15
    fig_size[1] = 12
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = fig_size
    base = "C:/Python36-32/GraphFactory/Final_csv.csv"

    conn1 = flask.request.args.get('conn1')
    conn2 = flask.request.args.get('conn2')
    sql1 = flask.request.args.get('sql1')
    sql2 = flask.request.args.get('sql2')
    charttype = flask.request.args.get('charttype')
    xlabel = flask.request.args.get('xLabel')
    ylabel = flask.request.args.get('yLabel')
    groupBy = flask.request.args.get('groupBy')

    #graph_title = charttype + "Chart"
    mdl.gen_csv(conn1, conn2, sql1, sql2)
    df = pd.read_csv(base)
    df_group = df.groupby(['YR', 'INSTANCE']).size()


    if charttype == "bar":
        mdl.bar_plot(xlabel, ylabel, 'Plot', df_group)

    elif charttype == "pie":
        mdl.pie_plot(xlabel, ylabel, 'Plot', df_group)

    elif charttype == "line":
        mdl.line_plot(xlabel, ylabel, 'Plot', df_group)

    elif charttype == "hist":
        mdl.hist_plot(xlabel, ylabel, 'Plot', df_group)

    #return send_file("plt.png", mimetype='image/gif')
    return flask.jsonify({"result":"<div class='user_avatar' style='background-image:url('/static/images/figure.png');width:240px;height:240px;background-size:cover;border-radius:10px;'>"})


app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=33)
```

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/my-css.css">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Graph Factory</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table class="headerTable" background="https://crunchify.com/bg.png"  width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="95%"><img src="static/SEILogo.png" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>


    <table style="width:50%" class="inputForm" align="center" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Connection
            </th>
            <th>
                Query
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="conn1" id="conn1"/>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <textarea name="sql1" cols="70" rows="8" id="sql1"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="conn2" id="conn2"/>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <textarea name="sql2" cols="70" rows="8" id="sql2"></textarea>
            </td>
            {#<td align="left">
                <a href="">Export CSV</a>
            </td>#}
        </tr>
        <tr class="top row">
            <td align="center">
                <label>X-axis Label</label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="xLabel" id="xLabel"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <label>Y-axis Label</label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="yLabel" id="yLabel"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <label>Group by Parameter</label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="groupBy" id="groupBy"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <label>Graph Type</label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <select name="charttype" id="dropdownchart">
                  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
                  <option value="pie">Pie</option>
                  <option value="line">Line</option>
                  <option value="hist">Hist</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="20" align="center">
                <button type='button' class='get_result'>Show Graph</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

 <div id='image_location'></div>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.get_result').click(function(){
         var conn1 = $('#conn1').val();
         var conn2 = $('#conn2').val();
         var sql1 = $('#sql1').val();
         var sql2 = $('#sql2').val();
         var xlabel = $('#xLabel').val();
         var ylabel = $('#yLabel').val();
         var groupBy = $('#groupBy').val();
         var dropdownchart = $('#dropdownchart').val();
         $.ajax({
       url: "/get_form_vals",
      type: "get",
      data: {conn1: conn1, conn2:conn2, sql1:sql1, sql2:sql2, xlabel:xlabel, ylabel:ylabel,
          groupBy:groupBy, dropdownchart:dropdownchart},
      success: function(img) {
        $("#image_location").html(img.result);
    },
      error: function(xhr) {
        print("error")
      }
      });
     });
   });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One way would be to use ajax or javascript to make the request and populate the element for you.

Comment: @Mick_ There is a bit of processing that goes on before the image is ready to be displayed due to thousands of lines being produced from the queries. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: As an alternative, consider using a client-side javascript plotting library (highcharts, c3, nvd3, there are a bunch) instead of server-side one (matplotlib). Process and format the data on the server then let the plotting happen on the client side. It allows you to have much more interactive plots (e.g. zooming, hover text, etc...).

Comment: @bnoos - I'm not Mick_ but basically you do something like... "user clicks button" > Display loading icon > send data to server > wait for server > after server responds, replace loading icon with your plot.

Comment: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask  check out this example. You can easily run the task as microservice if processing is involved. In the mean time update user on the progress and once task completes you can display it to the user.

Comment: Remember that flask is by default a single thread and single process application so it will block everything else if processing is involved so you should really consider microservice approach instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use `flask` with `ajax`. To do that, you will need to create a separate route to create the graph, savee the file, and return the HTML with the link to the image. Below is a slightly shortened solution showing how this can be done. Ensure that you have a `static/images` directory created, with `static` at the same level as `templates/` in your application folder:

in `main_app.py`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
 return render_template('my-form.html')

@app.route('/get_form_vals')
def form_vals():
  conn1 = flask.request.args.get('conn1')
  conn2 = flask.request.args.get('conn2'])
  #rest of vals follow
  plt.plot(x, y) #formulate your x, y values before
  plt.savefig('/app/static/images/filenameXYZ.png') #save to the images directory
  return flask.jsonify({"result":"<div class='user_avatar' style='background-image:url('/static/images/figure.png');width:240px;height:240px;background-size:cover;border-radius:10px;'>"})
```

Then, in `my-form.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <input type='text' id='conn1'>
  <input type='text' id='conn2'> 
  <!--rest of inputs follow -->
 <button type='button' class='get_result'></button>
 <div id='image_location'></div>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.get_result').click(function(){
         var conn1 = $('#conn1').val();
         var conn2 = $('#conn2').val();
         //get the rest of the vals
         $.ajax({
       url: "/get_form_vals",
      type: "get",
      data: {conn1: conn1, conn2:conn2}, //fill out rest of object
      success: function(response) {
       $("#image_location").html(response.message);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        //Do Something to handle error
      }
      });
     });
   });
 </script>

</html>
```

Comment: I implemented this code, but I'm not sure it works. Since it is navigating to `/get_form_vals` when the form is submitted, it is automatically loading a new page. This is the response I am currently getting. [picture](https://imgur.com/a/OA9H2)

Comment: @bnoos My apologies for not clarifying. When using `ajax` with `flask`, there is no need to create a form in the HTML with an action to the specified route. Only the `ajax` request specifies the route. Just set up the `<input>/<textarea>` fields and capture the input using `jquery` when the button is clicked. Do not worry about manually navigating to or specifying the route `/get_form_vals` anywhere other than the `ajax` itself. When running this particular example, the only page being served should be from `"/"`. Please let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah that actually cleared up a lot of the trouble I was having. Now for some reason, when I click the button, it bring up the menu to print the current screen. I can update the OP if it helps.

Comment: I updated the original post to show my code @Ajax1234

Comment: @bnoos Currently, you have two buttons defined with the same class: `<button type='button' class='get_result'></button>` and `<button type='button' class='get_result'>Show Graph</button>`. Try removing the former. Also, `filenameXYZ.png` is just a dummy filename. Ensure that you replace it with the name of the actual graph file. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Great that stopped the printing. I am debugging it with dev tools and it gets to success and sets the value of img to the return value of the flask method. However it is still not populating. What is the need of 'img.message'? @Ajax1234

Comment: @bnoos Can you clarify what should taking place when "populating"?

Comment: img is populated with  {result: "<img src="/static/images/plt.png" width="100" height="100" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">"} @Ajax1234

Comment: @bnoos Ah, I added that using bootstrap image syntax. Please see my recent edit for the new image html display in `flask.jsonify`.

Comment: Ah I see, but for some reason it is still not displaying the image in the div. I'll update the original post again. @Ajax1234

Comment: Since a json object is being returned, you need to call `$("#image_location").html(img.result)`, rather than `$("#image_location").html(img)`

Comment: I updated it to have img.result but it is still not outputting anything to the screen. Dev Tools shows no issues and states that img is being populated as `img = {result: "<div class='user_avatar' style='background-image:u…240px;background-size:cover;border-radius:10px;'>"}` I have no idea what the issue could be. I'm trying to mess with it but ajax is entirely new to me. @Ajax1234

Comment: I actually ended up fixing the use of apostrophes and double quotes in your response and it worked. Here is what I used:  `return flask.jsonify({"result":"<div class='user_avatar' style='background-image:url(\"/static/images/plt.png\");"
                                   "width:240px;height:240px;background-size:cover;border-radius:10px;'>"})`

Comment: @bnoos Ah, great!